# Почему a.pop(i) выводит значение, а b = a.pop(i) не выводит значение на экран

Tags: python, list

Есть список, я хочу по некоторому параметру удалять из него объекты, не понимаю, почему две реализации отличаются:

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 4]
for i in range(0, len(a)):
  if i == 1:
    a.pop(i)
  if i < len(a) : print(a[i])
```

Вывод  1 2 5 4
В то время, как

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 4]
for i in range(0, len(a)):
  if i == 1:
    b = a.pop(i)
  if i < len(a) : print(a[i])
```

Вывод  1 5 4

Почему так происходит? Куда возвращает значение функция a.pop(i)?

Comment: 1) Скрипты с ошибками, вам нужно определиться с отступами 2) присваивание `b` ничего не поменяет, поэтому алгоритмы должны выдавать одинаковый результ

Comment: если исправить отступы, то оба скрипта выдают одинаковый результат (Python 3)

Comment: @MaxU мой внутренний телепат утверждает, что на самом деле нет, см. ответ :)

Comment: @andreymal, я проверил и в iPython и запуском скриптов - оба раза вывод одинаковый...

Comment: @MaxU по-моему я вам уже когда-то говорил не вмешивать iPython лишний раз?) В обычном интерактивном python результаты на самом деле разные

Comment: @andreymal, у меня обычный интеракивный Python вызывает острую идиосинкразию

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что вы выполняете этот код в **интерактивной консоли.**

В ней любое выражение, результат которого не присвоен в какую-то переменную и отличнен от None, автоматически печатается на экран.

[image]

В первом варианте кода у вас есть никуда не присвоенное выражение `a.pop(i)` — это выражение даёт число, которое интерактивная консоль автоматически выводит на экран — то есть `2`.

Присваивания не являются выражениями, поэтому во втором варианте кода `b = a.pop(i)` ничего не даёт (кроме создания переменной), и интерактивная консоль ничего лишнего не выводит — выводится только то, что вы явно попросили вывести `print`ом.

При запуске `.py` файлов никакой магии, в отличие от интерактивной консоли, не происходит: если вы сохраните оба варианта в файлы и запустите их, они будут работать абсолютно одинаково и никаких лишних двоек не выводить.

[image]